# Como captura as horas em uma String?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou fazendo um código em javascript em que irei precisar dividir uma frase de modo que eu procure pelas horas, quero só o valor delas e de modo que eu consiga as separar, para colocar o valor separadamente.

```
Ex: 

String: 11:11 as 22:22 / 33:33 as 44:44 / 55:55 as 66:66

Saída: 11:11,22:22,,33:33,44:44,55:55,66:66

Saída 2: var1 = "11:11"; var2 = "22:22"; var3 = "33:33"; var4 = "44:44"; var5 = "55:55"; var6 = "66:66";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse regex simples resolve seu problema: `/\b\d{2}:\d{2}\b/g`

```js
let texto = '11:11 as 22:22 / 33:33 as 44:44 / 55:55 as 66:66'
const expressao = /\b\d{2}:\d{2}\b/g

console.log(texto.match(expressao))
```

- `\b` para que exemplos como `123456:789` não sejam retornados
- `\d` atalho para `[0-9]`
- `{2}` quantificador que pega exatamente dois números.
- `g` flag para encontrar todos os resultados possíveis.

**Detalhe**: O resultado resulta em um array, ai basta usar da forma que deseja!

Comment: Marconi, vou te incomodar um pouco :|  o `+` é um quantificador que é equivalente a `{1,}`, ou seja, "1 ou mais". É claro que sem o modificador `?` o `+` é guloso, mas acho que se não explicar que o mais é um quantificador pode ficar confuso para quem ler. De qualquer maneira a resposta está boa e já tem meu +1

Comment: E seria legar avisar que a regex casaria com `123456:789` também, se ele quiser limitar a apenas 2 teria que usar `\d{2}:\d{2}` ou `\d\d:\d\d`.

Comment: Como se trata de horários, eu acho melhor usar `{2}`  em vez de `+`, já que a quantidade de dígitos *parece* (pela descrição da pergunta) que será sempre 2. Só achei estranho que "33:33" e "44:44", etc sejam **horários**, pois pra mim o valor máximo de um horário é 23:59. Mas enfim...

Comment: Resposta atualizada, valeu pessoal :)

Comment: hkotsubo, estes valores da pergunta são apenas demonstrativos do formato, não são valores reais.

Comment: Obrigado Marconi, pela resposta e fernandosavio pela observação importante

Comment: Samuel, neste caso, sugiro que coloque sempre valores mais próximos dos reais, incluindo casos inválidos, pois dependendo do caso pode-se ter uma regex mais precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo:

```
var horariosFormatoInicial = '11:11 as 22:22 / 33:33 as 44:44 / 55:55 as 66:66';
var horariosSeparados = horariosFormatoInicial.replace(/ as /g, ' / ').split(' / ');
var saida1 = horariosSeparados.join(',');
var saida2 = '';

for (var i = 0; i < horariosSeparados.length; i++) {
    saida2 += 'var' + (i + 1) + ' = "' + horariosSeparados[i] + '"; ';
}
```

Nossa variável `horariosFormatoInicial` contém sua string original, sem formatação.

Em seguida criamos a variável `horariosSeparados` que será um array armazenando cada horário para utilizarmos na criação da `saida1` e `saida2`. Nela substituímos todos os trechos de texto `as` por `/`, assim teremos todos os horários divididos no mesmo formato.

> '11:11 / 22:22 / 33:33 / 44:44 / 55:55 / 66:66';

Agora podemos utilizar a função `split()`, passando o caracter `/`, para transformar no nosso array.

> [11:11, 22:22, 33:33, 44:44, 55:55, 66:66]

Agora podemos pegar nosso array e transformá-lo na Saída 1, utilizando a função `join()`, que pega cada elemento do array e o separa pelo caracter informado, que nesse caso é a vírgula.

Para a saída 2, utilizamos o `for` para percorremos nosso array e formatar a nova string no formato desejado.